# What would be the best way to program the save feature in a Text Editor-like program?

Tags: file, io

I was thinking about this for a small text editor-like program I'm doing, and one option (maybe the worst one) I can think of, is that whenever the user saves, the program overwrites the whole (previously saved) file with the new content. Other options like keeping track of what the user does with the text seem too much of a hassle to do. What would be the best way to program such feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we consider scalability; only option is to keep a track of all the changes user have done; and only save those changes during Save. This will also help you to implement Undo, Redo functionalities on your editor.

Keeping a track of all user changes can go to any extent making things more optimized but more complicated too and increases probability of conflicts too; I think easiest would be to track ONLY the lines changed rather than changing at word level.

No doubt, saving the whole thing is the quickest way to get things moving.